# navigation bar and status bar issue

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, uistatusbar

I am new to iOS.
I've created a xib file that contains a Navigation Bar (with title and a button) and a TableView.

**In iOS 7 the navigation bar overlaps with status bar**.
Is there a way I can programatically move the title and the button from the NavigationBar with just one row under the statusBar. I would like to have the status bad and the navigationbar included in the same bar.

I tried programatically to create a new NavigationBar after deleting from xib the NavigationBar I had but with NO SUCCESS. There is no Navigation Bar with no title when using this code:

/`/METHOD: -(void) viewDidLoad`

```
  [self.navigationItem setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:NSLocalizedString(@"New Title", nil)]];
        UIBarButtonItem *cancelTitle = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                                          initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Cancel", @"Cancel New Title")
                                          style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                                          target:self action:@selector(cancelNewTitle:)];
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = cancelTitle;
```

Comment: Which class is that viewDidLoad from?

Comment: I am extending UIViewController